# Модальные окна

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Как прописать значение текстового поля `<input id="tex" type="textarea">`?
Все процедуры должны происходить в модальном окне.

```
<?php
require_once "conf.php";
?>

<head>

<body> 
<?php

dbConnect();

$zapros=mysql_query("select * from spr_otdel") or die (mysql_error);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($zapros)){
echo "
<div class='panel' style='width:200px;'  id='d_{$row['id']}'>
{$row['id']}  {$row['name']}<div class='selo' ><a href='#' class='btn-delete'  onclick='return delet(\"{$row['id']}\")'>Удалить</a> | <a href='#' class='edit'>Редактировать</a></div></div>";
}
?>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
.panel {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px;
    position: relative;
    border-top: solid 1px #ccc
    }
.alt {
    background: #f5f4f4;
    }
.selo {
    font-size: 8pt;
    }
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".panel:even").addClass("alt");
        $(".panel .edit").click(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }

    }
]

 })})});

function delet(id) {

        $( "#del" ).dialog({ 
        title:"удаляем сообщение",
        buttons:
    {
        "Да": function() {
        $("#d_"+id).animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        $(this).dialog("close");},
        "Нет": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }

    }
 });     
        return false;

    }

</script> 
<div id="del" style='display:none;text-align:center;font-size:10px;'>
точно хотите удалить?
</div>
<div id="dialog" style='display:none;font-size:10px;' title='редактируем'>
<input id="tex" type="textarea">

</div>
</head>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, под textarea вы имели ввиду [многострочное поле](http://htmlbook.ru/html/textarea):

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="txt" id="txt">A multiline text</textarea>
```

В отличие от однострочного `<input type="text" id="txt" value="Single line" />` текст заключается между тегами. При этом из JavaScript можно обратиться к значению так же:

```
alert(document.getElementById("txt").value);
// или
alert($("#txt").val());
```

Comment: А как в alert($("#txt").val()); засунуть {$row['id']} ?